# How to copy to HDFS file and still retain permission?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have created a zero byte file with a specific owner and permissions as 600

```
-rw-------   3 cloudera hdfs         56 2014-04-01 18:47 Data/input/test.dat
cloudera:/home/cloudera
```

When I try to to run a copy via the api, I am seeing that it flips the permission from 600 to 644. How do I retain the permission? Any help will be appreciated.

**Before copy**

```
***>hadoop fs -ls Data/input/
Found 1 items
-rw-------   3 cloudera cloudera         10 2014-04-01 19:54 Data/input/test.dat
```

**After Copy**

```
***>hadoop fs -ls Data/input/
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   3 cloudera cloudera         10 2014-04-01 19:55 Data/input/test.dat
```

**Script which I have run**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

public class FilePerm{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Path src = new Path("/home/cloudera/input1.dat");
        Path tgt = new Path("Data/input/test.dat");

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        System.out.println(fs.getConf().get("dfs.support.append"));
        fs.copyFromLocalFile(src, tgt);
        System.out.println("Completed copy");
    }
}
```

To add, src is a file on Local UNIX file system and tgt is a file on HDFS.

Answer (score 2):

You're not copying a file, "copyFromLocal" really means "upload". You're really performing an upload, from a hdfs system into itself (are you sure that's what you want to do?).

Either way, the current hadoop client library doesn't check whether "local" is a hdfs based file system, and doesn't attempt to maintain permissions (or do anything with them, really). If you want to have specific permissions when using this system, you'll have to set them yourself (see [setPermission and FsPermission](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#setPermission%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.permission.FsPermission%29))

For your specific use-case, you might want to look at [FileUtil](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html), and make sure to specify two FileSystems (instead of two files).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was trying to look at options to lock down the hdfs files to only user or group (640) on hdfs while I am trying to copy them from local to HDFS.
Currently, copyFromLocalFile gives permissions during the time when the command is being executed. I can switch the permissions and owner after the copy using api but I don't want any other users on HDFS to even see my files momentarily.

Comment: try uploading to a directory which only you have access to.

Comment: I have access to upload to any directory. The problem is that I want to restrict the other users from using it while the copy is going on.

Comment: I said "only you" :P. create a directory, set permissions on it so they can't see it, and upload the files there.